# Цикл или explode работают неисправно

Tags: php

У меня есть файл с логинами и паролями (txt), содержимость файла такой

```
admin:1234
jack77:dan1el
```

со страницы login.php я отправляю данные на login-request.php и проверяю есть ли в какой то строке совпадение и вывести на экран, и для этого пользуюсь циклом , но цикл проверяет только первую строку

```
$fss = fopen("users/users.txt","r");

while($a = fgets($fss)){
    $x = explode(":", $a);

    if(trim($_POST['login']) == trim($x[0]) && trim($_POST['password']) == trim($x[1])){
        print_r($x);
    }
    else{
        $a = fgets($fss);
    }

}
```

Comment: Так вы разделите сначала строку по переносу `"\n"` или `"\r\n"`, а потом полученный элемент разделите по символу `":"`

Comment: а может https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php ?

Comment: Ну на самом деле и цикл и explode работают исправно. Неисправно в данном случае работает программист, написавший данные код :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() считывает из файла строку, указатель на чтение следующих данных при этом образно перемещается на 2ю строку, затем в конце цикла заново считываешь строку с помощью fgets() - и эти данные уходят в пустоту, потому что после этого цикл начинается заново, но указатель в файле уже на 3й строке.

Каждое чтение fgets() смещает указатель на следующую строку.

Вот правильный код:

```
$file = fopen("pass.txt", "r");

while ($line = trim(fgets($file))) {
    $login_pass = explode(":", $line);

    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['login'] === $login_pass[0] &&
        $_POST['password'] === $login_pass[1]) {
        echo 'логин/пароль найдены';
        //остановить цикл - break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите else, ваш цикл в любом случае будет проходить по всем линиям, а с тем что в else он будет пропускать каждую вторую строку до того, как найдёт и распечатает совпавшую.

PS: Используйте отладку для изучения поведения программы если не можете сделать это в голове для того чтобы понять поведение написанного вами кода.

Comment: а без else тоже не работает

Comment: Проверяет первую, ЕСЛИ не не совпало идет к следующему строку и так далее.

Comment: Вы, видимо, плохо изучили поведение и работу пост (do-while) и пре (while-do) циклов, почитайте про то как они работают.