# Выборка записей из Mysql с помощью IN где данные берутся из массива

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть массив, в нём список авторов:

```
['Dan Brown',
'Robin Sharma',
'John Green',
'Amish Tripathi']
```

Если вручную из массива подставлять в `IN` каждого автора оно работает:

```
SELECT *
FROM `borrowings`
JOIN `books` ON `borrowings.bookid`=`books.bookid`
WHERE `books.author` IN ('Dan Brown', 'Robin Sharma', 'John Green', 'Amish Tripathi');
```

А вот как правильно добавить этот массив в `IN` чтобы он работал?

Comment: скачать его (пример считывания https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268688/%d0%a6%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-explode-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be/1268717#1268717), разбить на элементы массива и циклом добавить в подготовленный запрос

Comment: пример вставки данных из массива в подготовленный запрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array

Comment: 1) Укажите **точную** версию MySQL. 2) Доступен ли файл для загрузки непосредственно в MySQL через LOAD_FILE()?

Comment: ` borrowings.bookid ` - это неправильная запись, которая вернет только ошибку

Comment: ` borrowings.bookid ` - правильная запись в ручную же всё работает.

Comment: Всем Спасибо, ответ уже есть

Comment: Это не ответ а костыль, который черз два дня сломается, и будет очень больно

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию, буду использовать тогда другой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При решении этой задачи необходимо помнить о главном правиле при работе с SQL запросами из РНР: если в запросе используются переменные, то в обязательном порядке этот запрос должен выполняться через пордготовленные выражения. То есть каждая переменная должна заменяться на знак вопроса, а сами переменные привязываться в запросу отдельно.

В данном случае сложность состоит в том, что мы не знаем заранее, сколько переменных у нас будет участвовать. То есть запрос получится динамический.

- сначала нам надо создать строку из вопросительных знаков через запятую по количеству элементов в массиве. Для этого нам послужит функция `str_repeat()`
- затем добавим эту строку в наш запрос. Хотя это и переменная, но в данном случае она безопасна, поскольку её содержимое полностью сгенерировано в коде РНР.
- затем надо подготовить запрос обычным способом
- затем надо привязать массив со значениями к запросу. Для этого нам понадобится составить строку с типами данных. Здесь нам снова поможет функция `str_repeat()`. Тип всегда можно использовать один и тот же, `s`
- после этого полученную строку с типами и массив с именами авторов передаем в функцию `bind_param()`, используя оператор распаковки аргументов.
- после этого выполняем запрос и получаем результат обычным порядком

В итоге получается такой код

```
$array = ['Dan Brown','Robin Sharma','John Green','Amish Tripathi'];
$in    = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?'; 
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM borrowings br JOIN books b ON br.bookid=b.bookid
          WHERE b.author IN ($in)";
$stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$types = str_repeat('s', count($array));
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$array);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: ток он из файла хотел загрузить))

Comment: Это делает его вопрос оффтопиком. Потому что вопрос должан быть один. Как читать файлы - это один вопрос, как делать SQL запросы - совсем другой

Comment: >>то в обязательном порядке этот запрос должен выполняться через пордготовленные выражения

проще говоря, необходимо использовать параметризованные запросы

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$namesString = implode(',', $names);

$query = "SELECT *
FROM `borrowings`
JOIN `books` ON `borrowings.bookid`=`books.bookid`
WHERE `books.author` IN ($nameString)";
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ага, а потом среди авторов будет John O'Hara, и полетит этот запрос в голубые дали...