# You have an error in your SQL syntax WHERE ID IN

Tags: php, sql

Мой sql запрос

```
$ru_str = "(310,350,69)";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status="publish" AND WHERE ID IN ('. $ru_str .') order by ID desc ';
```

при выполнении запроса выдает ошибку

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID IN (310,350,69,65,285,367,396,410,421,420,419,418,428,429,430,431,436,4' at line 1
```

По отдельности эти запросы выполняются `WHERE status="publish"` `WHERE ID IN ('. $ru_str .')` как только ставлю между ними AND, ошибка

Comment: AND WHERE ID IN ('. $ru_str .') 

1)  WHERE лишний (опечатка AND нужен)
2) скобки не нужны т.к. и так в строке (310,350,69)

3)так лучше не делать вообще

4)можно почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270068/15440

Comment: $ru_str = "(310,350,69)";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status="publish" AND ID IN ('. $ru_str .') order by ID desc ';